# Stack Overflow site for refactoring?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a good SE site that is only about refactoring?

I know there are sites like this, but SO has the largest audience of programmers so a section where you can just post a code snippet and people can give advice on refactoring it.

Comment: An *entire* site for this? What's wrong with just asking for help on SO? I think a good book would help a lot more than that.

Comment: Yeah, agree with GMan on that one.

Comment: thirded - this is a terrible idea sorry

Comment: http://refactormycode.com/ (which incidentally was used in the creation of StackOverflow - http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html and http://refactormycode.com/codes/360-balance-html-tags )

Comment: "An *entire* site for this?", @GMan, I agree, you are perfectly right! But why do we have *entire* site for golf, *entire* site for code review, *entire* site for super user, *entire* site for server fault, programming, ... That's a real site overkill, isn't it?

Answer (score 18):

For anyone currently browsing this question (October 2011), this currently exists at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (beta status).

Comment: You may want to update your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow could be used to do that.  In fact, [I've used it for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473087/string-benchmarks-in-c-refactoring-for-speed-maintainability) in the past.

I'd recommend a tag like `Refactoring` or `refactor-my-code` but either would work.

The 'question' part would be `How can I refactor this code for` *X* `?`

Comment: Actually, the best format for the title would be "How can I refactor this [language] code in order to achieve [your goal]?" where [your goal] might be "extensibility", "less memory consumption", etc.

Comment: Absolutely; whatever works. I couldn't care less about the actual text of the question; so long as it was descriptive and targetted. X = usability; speed; maintainability; conciseness.  The tags take care of which language he's talking about.

Comment: Code refactoring questions on SO are generally frowned upon, but may be acceptable in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

You undoubtedly seem to be looking for [**RefactorMyCode.com**](http://refactormycode.com/). This is a relatively new yet well-established site for anyone to come along and propose improvements/refactorings to your code, in a vaguely collaborative/wiki-like way.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to the other answers recommending [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) it should be noted that only real, fully working code is accepted there. Also you should describe what should be refactored in particular, and maybe add some description of your attempts.

Another option to ask for such from a more theoretical background (using a hypothetical code example) would be to ask at [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions), but as well you should show some effort about your ideas, research and attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you are looking for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)